# ltpara's new hook management and scrlayer-scrpage (for automatic paragraph counting, etc)

Tags: scrlayer-scrpage, hooks, lthooks

I have read that one should not use `\everypar` but rather `\AddToHook{para/begin}` for automatic paragraph enumeration and related operations. In principle, this works fine (mwe without counting, just printing a simple symbol):

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\AddToHook{para/begin}{*}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Once `scrlayer-scrpage` is loaded things go bad (see below). There appear to be a lot more paragraphs in the header and footer of the document that now apply the new `para/begin` settings. This issue does not arise with `\everypar`.

My question would be: how does `scrlayer-scrpage` manage `\everypar`, and why doesn't this work for `\AddToHook`? Is there an exclusion pattern one could use with `\RemoveFromHook` to avoid the issue?

[image: The above MWE with scrlayer-scrpage]

Comment: scrlayer-scrpage doesn't do anything with `\everypar`, but it uses `\parbox` 
and `\parbox` calls `\@arrayparboxrestore` which contains `\everypar{}`. You 
could add something similar for your hooks to `\@arrayparboxrestore`, but it 
is not clear if you really want to suppress your para-hooks everywhere where 
`\@arrayparboxrestore` is called, probably a more fine-grained control as 
suggested by @cabohah is better.

Comment: The  issue using `\everypar{*}`  is the same that   using `\AddToHook{para/begin}{*}` globally: that you have `\par`s everywhere, not only in headers and footers. They  also will type the "*" before sections titles, after the item numbers, etc.  Even if you can use a conditional to not type the * in some place, it can appear later in  unsuspected places. So, if you want this  only  in "normal" paragrahs, IMHO the best to avoid surprises is use that commands only locally, inside a group   (`{ }`)  o a environment (`\begin{whatever}  \end{whatever}` ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scrlayer` and `scrlayer-scrpage` do not use `\everypar` nor AFAIK generic hooks. But, e.g., `scrlayer-scrpage` uses several `\parbox` commands for the page head and page foot. So it has also several logical paragraphs inside the header and footer.

If you don't want to count paragraphs in page header and footer, you can use, e.g., a switch:

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\newif\ifatpageheadfoot
\usepackage[onpsinit=\protect\atpageheadfoottrue]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\AddToHook{para/begin}{\ifatpageheadfoot \else *\fi}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I believe `\ifatpageheadfoot` is what I was missing! Can you recommend a resource to find `\ifatpageheadfoot` and related things? Or does it come down to studying the source code?

Comment: @FelixEmanuel It is a new switch, I've defined in the example using `\newif`, which is a LaTeX kernel command and therefore a basic LaTeX feature. Setting it to true for the page header and footer is done using option `onpsinit`, which is documented in the KOMA-Script user manual. Instead of a boolean switch you could alternatively also use a command and redefine this in the page style initialization, if you are more familiar with that concept.